# How can I disable the sample data in trac

Tags: trac, sample-data

I just created my first trac project, but I don't want the sample data, how can I disable that.

I read the documentation and there is the `wiki remove` command. do I have to use this for all pages? Are there easy way to disable the sample wiki?

Comment: While your question is reasonable, please note, that these pages are not strictly *sample pages*. PageTemplates, TracIni and InterTrac come to mind. Wiki pages even form a part of the Trac configuration, i.e. InterMapTxt - *..the place for defining InterWiki prefixes*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modification of the behavior of 
`trac-admin <path_to_env> initenv` seems not even worth the hassle, because you only need to type

`trac-admin <path_to_env> wiki remove '*'`

into a system terminal to get rid of all default Trac wiki pages. You'll see a list of all deleted page names for confirmation. But you always make a db copy before messing with the db anyway, don't you?

Comment: Just a note, there's a script for it in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3984623/143979

Answer (score 2):

Sorry but there is no easy way to diable the sample wiki in trac. I'm pretty sure this can be done with a custom script, though.

Answer (score 0):

Trac stores the default pages imported into the wiki of a new environment as plaintext files in the file system.

For example, on my Gentoo box they can be found in `/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/trac/wiki/default-pages/`.

You can move these out of the way (or just keep those you want) before calling `trac-admin projectname initenv` and it will only create the pages that are in the ´default-pages` directory at the time of the call.